# Regular Expression to remove lines from a file

Tags: php, regex

I have a *.txt file which have unnecessary strings which look along the lines of:

`------------------------[ # ]-------------------------`

The problem persists that the `#` is any integer. I confused and are looking for a regular expression which finds the above string.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Specify more "look like this". Except the random number, does the length of those lines change?

Comment: whole file has this format :

------------------------[ 1 ]-------------------------
....
...
...
------------------------[ 2 ]-------------------------
....
...
...
------------------------[ 4 ]-------------------------

Comment: and length of those lines does not change

Comment: Please add a tag indicating which flavor/language you're working with.  And if it isn't Apple/iOS/Objective-C, remove the `nsregularexpression` tag.  That refers to a specific class, not regexes in general.

Comment: done, tnx alan ,i did't know that. Actually i have also added PHP tag to specify the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You best bet would be regular expression.

```
//read your text file into a variable named $filecont
/\-+\[\s\d+\s\]\-+(?:\r?\n|$)/g
//write the contents of $filecont to your file
```

The above will remove any lines that begin with 1 or more dashes followed by an opening bracket, followed by space, followed by 1 or more numbers, followed by space, followed by a closing bracket followed by 1 or more dashes.

Using the above regular expression will convert the following data

```
----------------[ 56 ]---------------------
Line of text
------------[ 929 ]--------------------
Another line of text
-----------------------------[ 1 ]----------
Last line of text
```

to

```
Line of text
Another line of text
Last line of text
```

Comment: this is a great answer because you included code, but given that this is not a specific framework, your regular expression being wired up in PHP is not the best.  Also, it's good to give a link or show the results of your code against example data.

Comment: Oops was looking in posts tagged php. Didn't notice this had nothing to do with it.

Comment: nothing to worry about, just passing along advice to the newcomers.

Comment: ُSorry Bluegman991, iam having a trouble with the code now, i think u have edited the post :-s
I get this error : Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier 'g' in E:\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\www\spliter.php on line 5 ... 
and nothing acctually happening =(

Comment: @Hell Lord The "g" is to tell it to match all. But in php it matches all by default so just remove the "g". Should look like this `$txt=preg_replace("/\-+\[\s\d+\s\]\-+(?:\r?\n|$)/", "", $txt);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regular expression:

`/((?:-+)\[\s\d+\s\](?:-+))/igs`

The expression will captures expressions with all numbers, from 0 to infinity.

Finally, I recommend using [this tool](http://www.gethifi.com/tools/regex) for new comers to the regular expression world, it helps visualise and understand how the regular expression works with your content.

Comment: It seems the flavor is PHP, so the `g` modifier is not supported.  And you aren't using the `.` metacharacter, so the `s` is irrelevant.